What is this SOIC-8 marked "BB REF / 02BU / 78GSY"?
I'm trying to identify an IC labeled BB REF / 02BU / 78GSY. It is an 8-pin SMD, in SOIC format.


That's not the part number.
It's a Burr-Brown (Texas Instruments) REF02BU.
A 5V precision voltage reference.
